# Nested directories - subimport and graphicspath

Tags: graphics, sectioning, import

I'm using the package `import` for chapters of a document. This makes it possible for me to use relative paths when I call `\input`. It also adjusts paths when I call `\includegraphics`. It does not, however, adjust the path when I call `\graphicspath`.

**Q:** How can I prepend the current sub-directory from `\subimport` to `\graphicspath`.

## Example

`paper.tex` contains:

```
\begin{document}
...
\subimport{subdirectory}{contents}
...
\end{document}
```

and `subdirectory/contents.tex` contains:

```
...
\graphicspath{images//}
\includegraphics{picture}
...
```

The error is then:

> LaTeX Error: File `picture' not found.

It is at `./subdirectory/images/picture.png`

---

**Edit:** I have posted my own unsatisfactory workaround to this problem below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my **current solution**. I redefine `\graphicspath` to inject the directory (in this case `subdirectory`).

```
  \let\gp\graphicspath
  \renewcommand*{\graphicspath}[1]{\gp{{subdirectory//#1}}}
  \subimport*{subdirectory//}{contents}
```

I then call `renewcommand` before each call to `subimport` with the same path.

---

This is **not optimal** for me, however, because it does not work if I enclose the path in a block, as in:

```
  \graphicspath{{images//}}
```

So, I've had to edit all the `graphicspath` calls to remove the blocks, as in:

```
  \graphicspath{images/}
```